# Assistance with a DELETE request in Postman

Tags: automated-testing, api-testing, rest-api, api, postman

I'm attempting to create some API tests to assist with getting familiar with API automation and I'm using the really helpful [Restful-Booker](https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com/) API for this. The API documentation is also [here](https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com/apidoc/index.html#api-Auth-CreateToken).

However I’m having an issue with the DELETE [request](https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com/apidoc/index.html#api-Auth-CreateToken) as given below

[image]

I’ve initially created a booking, then I’m looking to delete it but whenever I run the request through Postman I get a `403 Forbidden` error as below.

[image]

Would someone be able to point me in the direction where I may be going wrong with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide token generated create Token API here in header under cookie field.

and URL used in not as mentioned in API

https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com/booking/{bookingID}

Please check the screenshot here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Sid, thanks for your comment. How do I obtain the cookie from the "create booking API?

Comment: Hi @Andy use this API to get the token for your User                                           
          https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com/apidoc/index.html#api-Auth-CreateToken

Comment: Thanks Sid. And then do I then need to add this token when I create a booking, and then delete it later on? If you could provide screenshots of the flow you used that would help with my understanding

Comment: I think only delete requires the token and create booking does not has token in body, it requires all booking related data in body. I have attached screenshot for token creation and my bad i have mentioned there token generated in create booking API, it is separate API as mentioned in above comments. [edited my answer as well :) ]

Comment: That's great, thanks Sid. I've now been able to work this out. Out of interest what's the reasoning behind having to pass these tokens around?

Comment: I guess this is for security purpose, if we send plain text info in header related to user credentials, anyone can intercept and alter or misuse it so it is always better to generate some hashed/encrypted tokens in such scenarios.